# Кастомная карта с кастомными объектами с помощью Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, map, android-jetpack-compose

Всем здравствуйте. Имеется следующая задача: реализовать карту столов для ресторана. Приложение для Андроид, Jetpack Compose. Сразу скажу, что предпринималось: расстановка с помощью GridLayout, вычисление расположения и расстановка с помощью формул для разных экранов... Но все равно это не то (рис. 1)

[image: Попытка с помощью GridLayout]

2 года назад публиковался похожий запрос, но он не получил ответа. В целом, подобное требуется и мне (рис. 2)

[image: Похожее мне и нужно]

После чего возникла мысль использовать механизм создания обычной карты (как Яндекс Map или Google Map), сделать похожее, но собственноручно. Почему карта? Хотелось бы иметь скролл, подробный скроллу карты + маркеры для интерактива с пользователем. Никакой информации по этому поводу я не нашел, можете подсказать хотя бы материалы, направления и т.д для этой идеи?

Comment: Почему не то? А как вообще иначе? Как по мне, выбор лишь между кастомным layout или прямым рисованием на канвасе. Определяем наш масштаб и отображаем что надо чтобы не было сильно много элементов. Возможно каждый элемент должен иметь метку при каком приближении он виден. Или вычислять на лету упираясь в лимиты. Ну и....вот чем карта отличается от.... [интерактивного рыночного графика](https://habr.com/ru/companies/e-legion/articles/588657/)?!

Answer (score 1):

как бывший разработчик карт по типу яндекс и гугла советую туда не лезть.
если же надумаете, то вот в кратце:

сначала вам надо разработать векторные данные. нарисовать эти данные, заполнить их инфой (метаданными).
рисуются они в специальных картографический программах.

затем вам надо развернуть свой специальный картографический сервер и БД к нему.
из популярных (бесплатных) - MapServer или GeoServer
есть еще ArcGisServer, но лицензия стоит дорого (вроде от 10к$). за взломанные ничего сказать не могу.
с помощью этих серверов вы сможете превратить свои данные в карту.

карта может быть двух видов:
WMS (тайловая) - просто картинка. с ней взаимодействовать нельзя.
WFS (векторная) - карта, на которую уже можно тыкнуть и увидеть какую-то информацию.

результат этой работы получается в API.

далее, вам надо как-то подключить это API к вебу. для этого существую следующие библиотеки:
Leaflet, MapBox, Openlayers

в мое время у них не было библиотек под Андроид. только для вэба. (сейчас не знаю как дела обстоят)
поэтому дальше, когда у меня готовый локальный вэб проект, я его подключал в WebView, и писал дополнительные JS-скрипты, чтобы клики с WebVview на нужные мне элементы обрабатывались уже в коде Андроид-приложения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а что же тогда лучше использовать? Расстановку по координатам?

Comment: @aRINstotle к сожалению, не знаю. знаю лишь, что делать карту самому для этих целей - слишком трудозатратно и неоправданно.